# Android onKey w/ virtual keyboard

Tags: java, android

I am catching keyboard events/presses using the onKey method:

```
public boolean onKey(View arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
    //do something
    return false;
}
```

This fires off just fine for physical keyboard presses but it does not fire on virtual keyboard presses. Is there an event handler to handle virtual keyboard presses?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's an EditText, see if you can use a TextChangedListener instead.

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //do stuff
        }

    });
```

Comment: that did the trick! i'll post the code below since it doesn't format well in here, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Virtual keypresses are delivered directly to the selected view, they don't propagate through parent views like hardware keypresses. Are you overriding onKey on something other than the EditText/List/Whatever that's getting keypresses? (the thing you click on to get the virtual keyboard)

Comment: I am overriding onKey on my activity that implements onClickListener:

public class Foo implements OnClickListener{
..
public void onKey(View arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2){
  if(arg0 == searchBox){
    //do something
  }
}
..
}

where searchBox is an EditText

Answer (score 1):

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //do stuff
        }

    });
```