# onKey not called in Froyo 2.2

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I have several EditText fields that I reformat on the fly as the user types by looking for onKeyEvents from a onKeyListener on the views.  On a phone running 2.1 update 1 and a phone running 1.6, everything works correctly.  On a HTC EVO running 2.2, the onKey sub is never called. The activity implements View.onKeyListener, and setOnKeyListener(this) is set for each of the EditText views.

Comment: Great question - I got stuck on the exact same thing myself. Here's a great answer that was posted here on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051541/android-onkey-w-virtual-keyboard